# Custom mailer for other than admin and user in Devise Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a problem, with Devise. I created new role other than admin and user in devise Rails. Here how it looks like in  user.rb model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    PANEL_LEVELS = [PANEL_LEVEL_NORMAL = 'normal', PANEL_LEVEL_INACTIVE_MODERATOR = 'inactive_moderator', PANEL_LEVEL_DESIGNER = 'moderator']
```

When somebody creates new moderator account, it will become inactive moderator.

Main problem for me, is to send custom confirmation mail to moderator, this is how I tried to do it from custom_devise_mailer:

```
 def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts = {})
if record.class.name == 'User'
  opts[:template_path] = 'devise_users/mailer'
else if resource.panel_level == User::PANEL_LEVEL_INACTIVE_MODERATOR
       opts[:template_path] = 'devise_moderators/mailer'
     else
       opts[:template_path] = 'devise_admins/mailer'
     end
end
opts[:template_name] = :confirmation_instructions
super


end
```

Where

```
      resource.panel_level = User::PANEL_LEVEL_INACTIVE_MODERATOR if params.fetch('account') { nil } == 'moderator'
```

But it's sending default mail for devise_user.  Naturally I have views for moderator mailer, and method for sending it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statements are very twisted.
You can increase readability by simplifying them, by abstracting some logic into decorators.
I gues that you have decorators for Admin and User classes:

```
# in UserDecorator
def devise_mailer
  if object.panel_level = User::PANEL_LEVEL_INACTIVE_MODERATOR
    'devise_moderators/mailer'
  else
    'devise_users/mailer'
  end
end

# in AdminDecorator
def devise_mailer
  'devise_admins/mailer'
end
```

Having that your `custom_devise_mailer.rb` can be simplified to:

```
def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts = {})
  opts[:template_path] = resource.decorate.devise_mailer
  super
end
```

Comment: Thank you :) it's more transparent solution than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I created decorator for user:

```
 def inactive_designer
User::PANEL_LEVEL_INACTIVE_MODERATOR
end
```

With code above, I can use just inactive_moderator instead of typing     User::PANEL_LEVEL_INACTIVE_MODERATOR

And in custom_devise_mailer.rb

```
  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts = {})
if record.class.name == 'User' && record.panel_level != record.decorate.inactive_moderator
  opts[:template_path] = 'devise_users/mailer'
else if record.class.name == 'Admin'
       opts[:template_path] = 'devise_admins/mailer'
     else if record.decorate.inactive_moderator == record.panel_level && record.class.name != 'Admin'
            opts[:template_path] = 'devise_moderators/mailer'
          end
     end
end
```

Use the decorator and make a few conditional, to distinguish roles.